# Escape script tags when using jQuery AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to escape the script tags for content loaded in via AJAX with the following:

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'index.html',
    success: function(response) {

        $(response).find('<script').replaceWith('\x3Cscript');
        $(response).find('</script>').replaceWith('\x3C/script>');
```

However it gives an error that the TOKEN IS ILLEGAL...

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

you should escape the `/` with a forward slash, like in this snippet from the HTML5 boilerplate:

```
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

Like so:

```
$(response).find('<script').replaceWith(function(){return '<script';});
$(response).find('</script>').replaceWith(function(){return '<\/script>';});
```

Comment: Still getting the error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL `

Comment: @Cameron which line is throwing the error? are you able to reproduce this in a fiddle?

Comment: The second one `$(response).find('</script>').replaceWith('<\/script>');` You can see the error here: http://preview.na-software.co.uk/Demo/MarsPlaybook/preview.html

Comment: `replacewith` expects a DOM object or function. I believe updating the code above to include a function might solve your error. http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/

Comment: No luck with that either, gives the same error :(

Comment: can you reproduce this issue in a fiddle so I can debug further?

Comment: I'm not really sure how to fake the iframe loaded via AJAX in a fiddle

Comment: @Cameron theres actually a tab called `AJAX` requests that lets you do just that. Ultimately though you only need to include the `JSON` in a variable named `response` and then try your find replace code on it.

Answer (score 0):

Loading a whole page into a container can be done with `.load()`, i.e.

```
$('#iFrame').load('index.html', function() {
    // page loaded into container
    $('#iFrameLoading').fadeOut(function() {
        $('#iFrame').fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Comment: I need the script tags!

Comment: I write it to an iFrame see demo: http://preview.na-software.co.uk/Demo/MarsPlaybook/preview.html but the script tags need escaping first.

Comment: @Cameron Can't you just use `$('#iFrame').load('index.html');`?